# How to perfect little finger position

Tags: guitar, chords, technique, practice, exercises

I'm trying to playing a song using a Drop-D tuning in which i have to go from a G/F# to a Em7. The problem are basically two:

1. I'm not fast enough to place my little finger in place but this can
   be worked out by practicing
2. My little finger is not correctly placed and the string doesn't sound good, it buzzes but I seem to be unable to place it closer to the fret and/or straight it up a bit.

[image]

What can I do to improve the problem number 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are wrapping your thumb round the neck. If you place your thumb in the back of the neck it automatically opens up your hand so your fingers will stretch much further.

The reason for this is that when gripping the neck like a stick, all your fingers are designed to aim for your palm - so you physically cannot make your pinkie move outwards, but with your thumb in the back of the neck you can extend your fingers, and this allows the pinkie 2 or even 3 more frets in that position (just checked and I can just stretch 3 extra frets, but 2 is comfortable)

Comment: it works, even tho I cannot reach "2 or even 3 more frets in that position" :-)